# How to query points with a polygon layer using Bootleaf / esri-leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, point-in-polygon, esri-leaflet

I am using the [Bootleaf IAG framework](https://github.com/iag-geo/bootleaf).

I can not figure out how to get the bounding coordinates of a filtered layer.

I am modifying the bootleaf code to query points with a polygon layer. The Query Widget already allows users to draw a polygon, but I want to select a polygon from a layer hosted on my arcgis server. I modified the filter widget by removing the text field and allowing my users to select polygon layers and values from a dropdown menu. This works fine.

Now I need to take the result of the `layer.setWhere(where, handleError);` code and merry it with the query below. I need `selectedPolygon` to equal the result of `layer.setWhere(where, handleError);` and use the bounding coordinates in the `.within` section of the query.

I have tried a number of things, `L.latLngBounds`, `getBounds()`, and `toGeoJSON().features[0].geometry.coordinates` to name a few, but but I can not figure out how to pull out the bounds. What is the correct code?

```
    const query = L.esri.query({ url: pointInPolygonUrl })
        .token(pointInPolygonData.token)
        .within(selectedPolygon)
    query.run(function (error, data, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
```

6/8/2021 Edit (based on Seth Lutske's comment:

I did not provide a code sandbox for two reasons: 1 - bootleaf has a lot of files, 2 - all of my layers require secure sign in to arcgis. Hopefully I can provide enough information to get assistance without it.

1. Is `selectedPolygon` changing the way I am expecting? Currently there
   is no variable called `selectedPolygon` because I can not figure out
   the correct way to format it. `selectedPolygon` is what I want to
   call the filter result `layer.setWhere(where, handleError);`. I set
   the polygon layer up to filter on the map as the value changes. I
   can verify it is filtering as expected.
2. `selectedPolygon` format - This is where my problem lies. I can not
   seem to find the correct format based on how bootleaf layers are
   configured. I started with `var selectedPolygon =`
   `layer.features.geometry.coordinates;` and got a geometry undefined
   error. I proceeded to try every other code I could think of to get
   the bounds.
3. *Bounding coordinates* may not be the proper terminology. I want to
   run a query to find all of the points within the filtered polygon.
   To achieve this, it is my understanding that I need to use the
   bounds of the filtered polygon in the `within` section of the query.

6/8/2021 Edit #2

This [link](https://github.com/iag-geo/bootleaf/blob/master/src/js/app.js#L1605) may be most beneficial to show how the layer is constructed. I modified this code to remove the text input and add a dropdown, but the basic definition should be the same.

Line 1605 is `function addFilter()`

Line 1804 is `function applyFilter()`

Line 1927 is `layer.setWhere(where, handleFilterError);`

Photo 1: `console.log("polygon layer", layer)`

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5pEw.png)

Photo 2: Expanded `_layers`

[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rq6zQ.png)

Photo 3: Expanded `_rings` (I did not find `ToGetJSON`, but I found `ToGeoJSON` in this section.

[Photo 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tolZu.png)

It looks like if I can get to `_rings` then I should be fine, but that is where my knowledge is lacking.

Comment: [`within`](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/query.html#methods) can accept quite a few different kinds of geometry type arguments. **1** are you sure the `selectedPolygon` is changing according to your UI in the way you expect? **2** Is `selectedPolygon` in any of the accepted formats as described in the docs I linked? What format is it in? **3** You want to use the *bounding coordinates* of `selectedPolygon`, or the polygon itself, in the `within` query?  **!important**: As always, providing a codesandbox demonstrating the issue will make helping you much easier.

Comment: @SethLutske I added additional information above. Thanks

Comment: Reading that format is pretty difficult.  I'd say maybe post a picture of the console so I can make sense of it.  Or tell me how `layer` gets defined.  Is there a `toGetJSON` anywhere up the prototype chain on that (under the \_\_proto\_\_ property)?

Comment: @SethLutske I thought it might be hard to read. I remove that code and added additional information above.

Comment: Ok...interesting...a few things.  That code is 3000 lines long...very unreadable.  My recommendation is to modularize it for gods sakes!  Second. looks like the `layer` you're printing is `bootleaf.layers`...what is *that*?  I don't see any documentation about bootleaf's api.  The `rings` you see are [arcgis js api rings](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Polygon.html#rings), which each represent a single polygon, usually in a multipolygon layer.  Have you checked the \_\_proto\_\_ of `layer`?  Does it not contain `.toGeoJSON`?

Comment: After reading a bit more, it loos like bootleaf.layers is just an array container miscellaneous leaflet layers.  You can try calling `layer.toGeoJSON()`, and feeding that to the `within` query.  From your code its not clear what kind of layer `layer` would be in the context of the `applyFilter` function, but it sounds like its some type of esri-leaflet featurelayer, which *should* have a `.toGeoJSON()` method on it.  That should transform the layer into a geometry format that `within` can understand and filter with.

Comment: @SethLutske I agree. The code is massive. I assume the intention is to provide everything that might be needed with the framework and allow developers to remove what they don’t need. That is my plan, but I am not there yet. 

`var selectedPolygon = layer.toGeoJSON();` yields an error: Uncaught TypeError: layer.toGeoJSON is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about bootleaf, but here are some tips to get you started.  Based on your question and comments, this will hopefully clear things up and instruct you on how to apply what you need in your scenario.

### Hook UI to `setWhere`

When the user selects an option from the UI, you can call `setWhere` on the layer you're providing from the arcgis server.  Let's say there's a polygon layer, in my example, called `statesFeatureLayer`, which `is an L.esri.featureLayer`

```js
// Create polygon layer of states
const statesFeatureLayer = EL.featureLayer({
  url: "polygon_featurelayer_url_from_arcgis_server"
}).addTo(map);
```

And there's a point layer:

```js
// Create points layer
const pointsFeatureLayer = EL.featureLayer({
  url: "points_featurelayer_url"
}).addTo(map);
```

Now there is some UI, which has to trigger `setWhere` to be called on this layer.  So anywhere in the UI where you want to run this functionality of setting the filter on the layer, and then querying the other layer based on the results, we'll run a function call `runQuery`:

```js
function runQuery(){
  statesFeatureLayer.setWhere(querystring, callback)
}
```

### Run callback after `setWhere` fires

It sounds like you've already got this part figured out, and that your `setWhere` function is running properly.  However, `setWhere` also takes an optional callback function as its second argument, which runs after the `where` has been set and the layer refreshed.  Let's dig into that. In the callback, we're going to want to get all the features that are currently active on the map:

```js
function runQuery(){
  statesFeatureLayer.setWhere(querystring, () => {
    statesFeatureLayer.eachActiveFeature(feature => {
      // do something with features
    })
  })
}
```

### Run query to test points layer against active features of polygon layer

Within `eachActiveFeature`, we can run a query on the `pointsFeatureLayer`:

```js
function runQuery(){
  statesFeatureLayer.setWhere(querystring, () => {
    statesFeatureLayer.eachActiveFeature(feature => {
      pointsFeatureLayer
        .query()
        .within(feature.toGeoJSON())
        .run((error, data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    })
  })
}
```

So now were are running a query which asks for any points in the `pointsFeatureLayer` that are in the geometry of each active feature of the `statesFeatureLayer`.

The downside of this is that we can't run a query against all the active features as a group.  The `within` query method (along with most of the other [query methods](https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/api-reference/tasks/query.html#methods)) can accept singular features, whether in the form of an L.Polygon, L.Polyline, or an L.GeoJSON.  While I had tried creating an L.featureGroup and calling `.toGeoJSON` on that, `within` seems to require a GeoJSON that describes only a single shape.  So if you have multiple features, you'll have to conglomerate them.  For example, you may have some variable `results = []` at the global scope level, then within the callback of `run`, you can push the results to `results`, which will give you all results in one variable. This may take some massaging in js to get it right.

### [Working Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/esri-leaflet-featurelayer-86pup)

Here you have 2 UI elements which cause `runQuery` to run.  Either the dropdown, or the checkbox.  You'll see that on every UI change, `setWhere` is called with a querystring constructed from the UI (setWhere for a state, and setwhere for that state and california if the checkbox is checked).  When `setWhere` is called, its callback then runs a query against the point layer just for the currently active features, and then returns whatever points from the pointlayer are `within` each of the active features.

Comment: Spot on mate. A modified version of the `function runQuery()` did the trick. I think it had to do with the use of `eachActiveFeature(feature =>`. Thank you very much!